# Exercise 4 on p.38 in Exercises 2B in "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler. Is my solution ok?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, borel-sets

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 4 on p.38 in Exercises 2B in this book.

> Exercise 4
> Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\{(r,n]: r\in\mathbb{Q},n\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$
> Prove that $\mathcal{S}$ is the collection of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

We use the following result to solve Exercise 4:

> Exercise 3
> Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\{(r,s]: r,s\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$
> Prove that $\mathcal{S}$ is the collection of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

My solution is here:

> Let $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}.$
> Let $n$ be an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $s\leq n.$
> Then, $(r,s]=(r,n]\cap (\infty,s]=(r,n]\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus (s, n+1]).$
> So, $(r,s]\in\mathcal{S}.$
> By Exercise 3, the collection of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{S}.$
>
> Let $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$
> Then, $(r,n]\in\{(r,s]: r,s\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$
> By Exercise 3, $\mathcal{S}$ is a subset of the collection of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

Is my solution ok?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: It is ok but a bit heavy: in the second part, you could just argue that $(r,n]$ is a Borel subset and in the first part, that $(r,s]=(r,n]\setminus(s,n].$

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much for your answer.